# Unable to Find Error

Tags: c#

I am getting an error with my program and I am not able to resolve the issue. The issue is arising when I try to assign user input to the variables in my class.

The two variables in questions are: Quantity_Of_Order (string) & Date_Of_Purchase (string)

With Quantity_Of_Order, I am trying to assign it the value entered in a text box. 
With Date_Of_Purchase, I am trying to assign it the value chosen in a date time picker.

I tried to output the values and am getting this displayed:

> Quantity of Order: System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 200
>   Date of Purchase: System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker, Value: 01/04/2014

When I try to use Quantity_Of_Order, my program stops working and I get this message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format

Here is my code for getting input and assigning it the variables in my class:

```
//This method sets the value of Quantity_Of_Order based on the amount entered by the user
    void Set_Quantity_Of_Order(int identifier)
    {
        string quantity = txtQuantityOrdered.ToString();//txtQuantityOrdered is the text box where user enters value
        Order[identifier].Quantity_Of_Order = quantity;
    }

//This method sets the value of Date_Of_Purchase, based on the date entered by the user
    void Set_Date_Of_Purchase(int identifier)
    {
        string purchase_date = dtpPurchaseDate.ToString();//dtpPurchaseDate is the date time picker where user selects date of purchase.
        Order[identifier].Date_Of_Purchase = purchase_date;
    }
```

I am sure I have just made a noob mistake because I am new to C#. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your title to make it more descriptive. Right now it says aboslutely nothing about the type of problem you're having. If you already haven't, read [ask].

Comment: @dandan Sorry as I am new to this I didn't know how best to describe the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `txtQuantityOrdered.ToString();` but

```
txtQuantityOrdered.Text
```

And

```
dtpPurchaseDate.Text
```

Or

```
dtpPurchaseDate.Value
```

The last one outputs a `DateTime` object.

Comment: Thanks mate, that seemed to have done the trick. I knew I was missing something simple but had a mental block as to what it was. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3478049: No problem. Since you are new, please don't forget to mark your question as answered if the answers were helpful.